# Is there a way to obtain the raw image from a Norton Ghost file?

Tags: linux, norton-ghost, dd

I have a Norton Ghost .gho file, and basicly I want to extract the raw image out of this, for example to use with with tools like dd. (So using any symantec/windows tools is not an option). Is there any open source tool which can deal with these .gho files ?

(Note: the.gho file I'm using is a sector based one, and not a file-based one, which implies that things such as Ghost explorer won't work either (see [this page](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/ghost-explorer))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [VMware vCenter Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) should convert it to a VMDK.

Then use [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page)'s [qemu-img](http://www.penguin-soft.com/linux/man/1/qemu-img.html) to convert to other formats.

Comment: I have Converter 5.0.1.  It is unwilling to accept a .gho file as input.  The documentation at http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/converter_pubs.html indicates that it converts "Norton Ghost version 10.0, 12.0, and 14.0 (only .sv21)".  None of the documents for older versions back to 3.0.3 of Converter at that URL mention .gho compatibility.  How was Converter used to translate the .gho to a .vmdk file?